# Wordpress (Divi): add category of post in sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, categories, sidebar

[image]

Site: [ArboCityNet](https://www.arbocitynet.ch/de/startseite/)

I would like to add the category of the post in the sidebar widget (It's a widget, which shows me the latest/newest posts).
With the Plugin "what the file" I could see, what files are being used:

[image: Files]

I googled, what I have to add: [Wordpress wp_get_post_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/)

But I'm not sure, where to change or add this phrase of code to show the category of the post in the sidebar.

Can someone help me with that problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

wp_get_post_categories() is a wordpress function you can add it to Functions.php file in your theme (This is coding thing create shortcode and then paste it to sidebar), But if you are Using Divi then there is pre-built widget available and you just need to Drag that on sidebar.
On wordpress admin panel Navigate to:
Apperance => Widgets
Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/vc02h4

And drag this widget to the sidebar with is running on the website.
Please let me know if it helps you!

Thanks

Comment: Hello thanks for helping me! It is not that what i want. I would like to have for each post to show the category. (view my screenshot) and I think in that case I need to change something in the code?

Comment: Got it, You want to show the category name of post at the bottom of every post title. For this I need to know which widget you are using. This can be done with code. Send me screenshot of widget which you are using in sidebar, then I will let you know what exact code you need to add because every widget have their own hooks.

Comment: Ah sorry! Yes, the widget is: Orange Themes Custom Widgets :)

Comment: I have checked the files this 'Orange Themes Custom Widgets' widget and there is no hook available for add category or any other thing in posts loop. And one more Thing this plugin is Outdated.  Last updated: 4 years ago [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/orange-themes-custom-widgets/) 
I would recommend you to use different plugin for this :) 
If you need help on finding plugin then I can do. But for that you have to give answers of some of my questions
Are you showing Recent posts in widget? Order of posts is ascending of descending? It is hard to write all questions on one comment.

Comment: Are you showing all posts or only from specific category? Any other setting you have added in Orange theme widget?

Comment: Okay. The plugin was already installed, thats why I used it. Yeah it would be great if you could help me. I show recent posts from 2 categorys. I think ascending? The newest on the top? other setting: title, image should be hidden, post count: 3, offset: 0, and should work with languages (only showed in DE / FR). I also ask myself, if its possible to add dynamic content in there then? (I work with the plugin ACF) f.E. i need to add the date of the event and not the date of the publish of the post. thanks for your help! :)